# Question on displaying overflow (scrollbars)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, overflow

I have a main page coded as follows;

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>

 <body>
 <table height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="646" class="data border">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="noPad">
                    <iframe height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" name="studentFrame" src="delete2.html"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the iframe page is coded as;

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>

 <body>
  <table height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="834" class="data border">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>
                  <td>123</td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I want the iframe to scroll horizontally in the main page..

Will it scroll naturally as width of iframe is more than width of main containing table OR do we need to explicitly specify any attribute?

please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you even tried it? [Works fine for me](http://jsbin.com/ozawu4). The problem could be if the height of the iframed content exceeds the height of the iframe.

Comment: "Will it scroll naturally as width of iframe is more", try it yourself?

Comment: It scrolls for me, but does not show the horizontal scrollbars ...

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are you sure you're reffering to "horizontal" correctly? A horizontal scrollbar would be one that you could safely place your cup of coffee on top of, while a vertical scrollbar would be something that you could lean against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend putting I-frames in tables, or even using tables at all in this scenario.

You can disable overflow for elements on the main page:  for the iframe and the table td. 
overflow:hidden;

And then for the body of your iframe page you can do 
overflow-x:scroll;

or you can try it for the actual iframe class.

Comment: What is the default value of overflow for table td, iframe ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be any overflow with the td. As far as I can remember the td's content pushes the height of the td. Not sure for Iframes sorry